# Basis for permutation invariant states

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, bell-basis

It is known that the maximally entangled qubit states form a basis (the Bell basis). Let $\Phi$ be the canonical maximally entangled state i.e.

$$\Phi = \left(\frac{\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\langle 00\vert + \langle 11\vert}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Let $\Phi^\perp = \mathbb{1} - \Phi$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the maximally mixed state on two qubits.

Let $P_{k}^{n}\left(\Phi, \Phi^{\perp}\right)$ denotes the summation of $n$-fold tensor products of $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{\perp}$ with exactly $k$ factors of $\Phi$. For example, $P_{1}^{3}\left(\Phi, \Phi^{\perp}\right)=\Phi^{\perp} \otimes \Phi^{\perp} \otimes \Phi+\Phi^{\perp} \otimes \Phi \otimes \Phi^{\perp}+\Phi \otimes \Phi^{\perp} \otimes \Phi^{\perp}$.

Do the terms $P_{k}^{n}\left(\Phi, \Phi^{\perp}\right)$ where $1\leq k\leq n$ form a basis for states that are invariant under permutation of the $n$ registers? That is, can any permutation invariant state of dimension $4^n$ be uniquely written as

$$\Psi = \sum_k c_k P^n_k(\Phi, \Phi^\perp)$$

If yes, how do I see why this is the case?

EDIT: Corrected dimension based on answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take the case $n=k=1$. Then your basis contains a single element, $\Phi$, whereas the permutation-invariant subspace of two qubits has dimension 10.

More generally, there's no need to reinvent the wheel, it's easy to construct an explicit basis for the permutation-invariant subspace.

EDIT: I don't know a reference for the construction, but it's easy to to it yourself. Let $\{\sigma_i\}_{i=0}^{d^2-1}$ be a Hermitian basis for the Hilbert space (e.g. the usual generalized Gell-Mann matrices). You need to generate the list of indices that are equivalent under permutations. There are $\binom{n+d^2-1}{n}$ non-equivalent indices. For example, for $n=2$ and $d=2$ the list is

`00`

`01` `10`

`02` `20`

`03` `30`

`11`

`12` `21`

`13` `31`

`22`

`23` `32`

`33`

Then each element of your basis will be the sum of the tensor product of the Gell-Mann matrices of a given line, e.g.,
$$\sigma_0 \otimes \sigma_0$$
$$\sigma_0\otimes\sigma_1 + \sigma_1\otimes\sigma_0$$
$$\sigma_0\otimes\sigma_2 + \sigma_2\otimes\sigma_0$$
and so on.

Generating this list of indices is a straightforward but tedious exercise in combinatorics. [QETLAB](https://qetlab.com/Main_Page) can automate it for you.

Comment: Thank you - is there a good reference to learn about this construction?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Your dimensions don't appear to work out. You're considering states of dimension $2^n$, but when $n=1$ you've written down a state for a Hilbert space of dimension $4$.

Anyway, I don't think $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\perp$ are good states to consider, even if we just consider $n=1$. Consider $(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)(\langle 01|+\langle 10|)$. There's no way to write this as a combination of $\Phi$ and $\Phi^\perp$.

In general, it's hard to see how this construction could get you all pure symmetric states, since you're looking at linear combinations of a pure state $\Phi$ and a mixed state $\mathbb{1}$.